# Convert to Scala code PEM to DER Certificate Follow it up from Google KMS Library

Tags: java, scala

I am new to Scala and was trying to convert this:

```
  public static byte[] convertPemToDer(String pem) {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(pem));
            String encoded =
                    bufferedReader
                            .lines()
                            .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("-----BEGIN") && !line.startsWith("-----END"))
                            .collect(Collectors.joining());
            return Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
        }
```

to Scala code:

```
def convertPemToDer(pem: String): Array[Byte] = {
    val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(pem))
    val encoded = bufferedReader.lines.filter((line: String) => !line.startsWith("-----BEGIN") && !line.startsWith("-----END")).collect(Collectors.joining)
    Base64.getDecoder.decode(encoded)
  }
```

It shows this type mismatch within filter:

```
type mismatch; found : String => Boolean required: java.util.function.Predicate[_ >: String]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your imports. I could run your code by using these imports:

```
import java.io.{BufferedReader, StringReader}
import java.util.Base64
import java.util.stream.Collectors
```

The code compiled and ran just fine. I just added a `println` at the end:

```
object Main extends App {

  def convertPemToDer(pem: String): Array[Byte] = {
    val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(pem))
    val encoded = bufferedReader.lines
      .filter((line: String) =>
        !line.startsWith("-----BEGIN") && !line.startsWith("-----END")
      )
      .collect(Collectors.joining)
    Base64.getDecoder.decode(encoded)
  }

  println(convertPemToDer("Elephant").mkString("Array(", ", ", ")"))

}
```

Output:

```
Array(18, 87, -87, -123, -87, -19)
```

If you are not using Intellij with the Scala plugin, your IDE might not be able to recognize `Functional Interfaces` as `Single Abstract Methods`. So you might need to adapt your code into a more Java-style approach, like this:

```
  def convertPemToDer(pem: String): Array[Byte] = {
    val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(pem))
    val encoded = bufferedReader.lines
      .filter(new Predicate[String] {
        override def test(line: String): Boolean =
          !line.startsWith("-----BEGIN") && !line.startsWith("-----END")
      })
      .collect(Collectors.joining)
    Base64.getDecoder.decode(encoded)
  }
```

Comment: It shows compilation issue to me. 
type mismatch;
 found   : String => Boolean
 required: java.util.function.Predicate[_ >: String]

Comment: Are you using any specifc scala version. I tried using your sample code creating new scala project and getting the same problem. type mismatch;
 found   : String => Boolean
 required: java.util.function.Predicate[_ >: String]
      .filter((line: String) =>

Comment: My Scala version is 2.13.8 with JDK 15

Comment: Does it work with JDK1.8 as I am using JDK1.8 ?

Comment: It's not about JDK, it's about the IDE your are using, it does not recognize Single Abstract Methods. Check my post again, I edited it at the bottom and added another solution that should work for you, with the explanation. Let me know if that solves your issue.